# Calculating the information contained in a message

Tags: machine-learning

Lets say i want to calculate the information content of a particular message.What apart from the message itself has to be taken into account in doing so, and what data would i need to collect to perform my action?

Answer (score 3):

Using notions like entropy (like in Ashok's answer) only work if you believe the message is coming from a specific distribution. If all you have a single message, then the only measure of complexity that's meaningful is the [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) of the message, which is sadly uncomputable.

Comment: Suresh is right -- in classical information theory, the information content of a single message isn't defined. You can only measure information content for some ensemble (distribution) of signals.

Answer (score 2):

May be, one needs to estimate the frequency $p(m)$ of occurrence of the message $m$. Then $\log \frac{1}{p(m)}$ is the information content of the message $m$.

Comment: This is a nice answer.  The quantity $h(m) = \log 1/p(m)$ can be conceived as the "surprise" of seeing message $m$ (it's a decreasing function of the probability of encountering message $m$ -- if we always observe this message then $p(m)=1$ and surprise $h=0$.).  This quantity averaged over the distribution of all messages $p(m)$ is the Shannon entropy.  So the surprise of seeing $m$ is the contribution of that message to the total entropy, but it's not really an "information" in the classical sense.